# Android TextClock text formatting issue

Tags: android, clock, datetime-format

android.widget.TextClock format the 12 hour text using 'format12Hour' is not working properly on Android Lollipop and above.

It's set as 'hh:mm:ss aa' and shows correctly on Kitkat as '12:10:15 PM' but in Lollipop & Marshmallow, AM/PM is showing as a.m. & p.m. (dots in between & the letter is lowercase).

So Please Help Me.

Comment: Found any solution to this? I am seeing this issue in only few devices but not all above Lollipop.

Comment: I did a workaround that time which is used even now also. Didn't checked whether its causing issue, with the default behavior, now also. The issue was found on multiple devices.